# Examples of a decision ruled by voting of Sanhedrin in the Talmud

Tags: halacha-theory, beit-din-court, sanhedrin

If I understand correctly the Peshat of the Torah ([Deut 17](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.17.8?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he&with=Targum%20Jonathan%20on%20Deuteronomy&lang2=he)), when a Machlokes raises, there's a simple and Kosher way of resolving it - gathering the High Court and voting on it and, of course, following the majority.

EDIT: There are several places where the Gemmorah mentions the procedure in very general terms, like "נמנו וגמרו" (were counted and decided), however, it appears to refer to a random gathering of particular Chachamim, and not to a wider authoritative forum. I don't understand how voting and the decision are valid in such cases.

Are there examples in the Gemmorah where the outlined procedure was maintained: that a specific Halachic ruling was ruled by gathering the High Court, put on voting between the Chachamim, voted for, the votes counted and the decision proclaimed and accepted?

Comment: Sure, search any Torah database for נמנו וגמרו ([the votes] were counted, and they decided that X). The first couple of halachic examples in the Bavli are Shabbos 81a and Chagigah 3b.

Comment: @meir and the 18 things in the first perek of Shabbos

Comment: you want to know the names and who exactly numbers of votes for and against? probably the only time where we know exact numbers was when it was 1 against 70 was Zecharia ben avkulus ruling against the rest of Sanhedrin in Gittin 57a twice and his opinion still got accepted as he was the greatest in knowledge and bar kamza wasn't killed and the Korban of the Ceasar wasn't brought

Comment: @Heshy True, I searched only for נמנו וגמרו, not just נמנו (as it is there).

Comment: @user15464 I opened https://www.sefaria.org.il/Gittin.57a?lang=he but I don't see זכריה on that page.

Comment: @AlBerko sorry i meant https://www.sefaria.org/Gittin.56a.4?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he

Comment: @user15464 I'm sorry, where do you see voting and counting in this episode? Where do you see the number 70? Where do you see a ruling? In my reading, this story is completely "non-Halachic", it does not teach us a Halacha at all, don't you agree?

Comment: @Meir Thank you, many agreed with you. I edited the question.

Comment: Even with the edit, we have examples such as בו ביום נמנו וגמרו (Yadayim 4:1ff). The gathering on בו ביום - when they had 72 elders there (Zevachim 1:2) - was most definitely an (actually, for the time, _the_) authoritative body.

Comment: @Meir https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Zevachim.1?lang=he? Can you post a link, please.

Comment: @Meir Yadayim doesn't mention any number or place or audience.  R"Sh ben Azay mentions being guided by 72 but it is irrelevant to נמנו וגמרו, IMHO.

Comment: Yadayim mentions בו ביום, which as we know from the Gemara (Berachos 28a) refers to the time when Rabban Gamliel was deposed and R' Elazar ben Azaryah appointed. The Mishnah in [Zevachim 1:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Zevachim.1.3?lang=he) (sorry, gave the wrong reference before) mentions שבעים ושנים זקן ביום שהושיבו את ר' אלעזר בן עזריה בישיבה, which is the same occasion.